# Simple code for create a thread in Python 2.7

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to do a simple thread as follows.

```
import threading

def func(x):
    print x

t1 = threading.Thread(target=func,args=("Hello",));
t1.start();
```

Then I got following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import threading
  File "/Users/treinetic-macbook/Desktop/threading.py", line 2, in <module>

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 3, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 207, in <module>
    _lock = threading.RLock()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RLock'
```

can someone help me to understand this error?

Comment: No problem in your code, its executing here

Comment: Same here no error. You probably need to make sure your packages are up to date?

Comment: try with -O **python file_name.py -O** or can you please rename file to something else e.g. mythreading.py or anything?

Comment: Looks like you have a module or package named `threading` locally which is imported instead.

Comment: my money's on him having a macbook being the problem :)

Comment: It has to be mac @omu_negru

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/Users/treinetic-macbook/Desktop/threading.py` is being imported because it's on your path somewhere.  This is most likely not correct, try renaming that file and removing any `threading.pyc` file in your local dir.